# Registration Form (profile) with selected groups only?

Tags: profile, groups

I try to set up a user registration form (for the Front End) using a profile. Within the profile the groups should be listed, but just selected ones, not all. I could not find a switch for this.  Is this generally possible just to define the groups to be listed?
Thank you for your hints.

Comment: if your CMS is Drupal then webform might give you more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

Visibility: Public Pages will be listed; Check your group Admin screen at:

```
civicrm/group?reset=1
```

If you're also seeing Groups in your Profile select that are listed as Visibility: User and User Admin Only - do let us know.

**Added**: if you don't want all your Groups that are configured Public Pages to be listed then try this:

- create a custom field
- add the custom field to the profile
- create a smart group - that has your custom field in the search criteria

Comment: Wow, that was fast... Thank you for your answer. It is as you mentioned all public groups are listed, but for this specific profile I need to offer only 2 specific out of 8 public groups. But may be I an doing it wrong at all. 

The intention is that an interested party may request a specific document (curriculum), and by local law we need the double opt-in provided by the group/newsgroup functionality to send this information out.

Comment: Hi - I've added to my answer - give that a try!

Comment: I will try, but first I have to solve a problem when creating a custom field.

Going to Data and Forms -> custom field I just got an empty page...

Comment: Empty as in white?